# Core Data request with restriction

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm searching how to do particular request like if they're a WHERE on the request, I don't know if it's possible with Core Data, I only know how to fetch a table:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Demandes")
let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

if results.count > 0 {
    for item in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

        // let id = item.valueForKey("id")
        let id = item.valueForKey("id")
        let xml = item.valueForKey("xml")
        let statutenvoie = item.valueForKey("statutenvoie")
        let dateenvoie = item.valueForKey("dateenvoie")

        // print(item.objectID)
        print(id!, xml!, statutenvoie!, dateenvoie!)
     }
}
```

But I wan't to search if they're lines where the attribute statutenvoie is equal to 1.

Comment: Use a `NSPredicate` to your `NSFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSPredicate is what you need.

Many tutorials online, for example:

http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-25070

Comment: I don't understand how to integrate nspredicate with nsfetchrequest